# Language Understanding: How to check whether two tasks or todos are same or not?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Are there any standard algos which given two queries/tasks/todos and tell me whether they are same or not? The way I'm thinking is that if somehow I can extract the intent of the task and entities involved in it and check them with that of the other task. But I'm not sure whether this approach will work in all scenarios or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use some existing libraries like Opennlp(if you're good with java) or NLTK(for python) or any other good ones to do POStagging and then you can compare for different parts of the statement like verb phrases to check if the statements are the same.